# How to turn off ssl for specific url?

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

Here is my config:

```
upstream example {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/example/shared/tmp/sockets/example-puma.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.org;

    location /non_https {
        proxy_pass http://example;
    }

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

  listen 443 ssl default_server;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  root /home/deploy/apps/example/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @example;
  location @example {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://example;
  }

  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I need to turn off ssl for /non_https/* how to get it?

Comment: Warning: it's insecure to do that, because it's mean you can't use HSTS, so all https pages are vulnerable to sslstrip attacks.

Comment: But I want to turn off https only on a specific url, other urls should use https

Comment: That's my point: you can't use HSTS because you need http on some urls. Others url with https are then vulnerable to sslstrip because you don't use HSTS. A solution could be to use another domain for http urls. May I ask why do you need http?

Comment: http is needed for externel system, which couldn't use https. Why all https pages would are vulnerable? Can I use subdomain.example.org for http, but anyway it will be on the same IP?

Comment: If it's for a system which don't understand https, then you can activate HSTS and keep http only for that system. Remember: HSTS is the only protection against mitm/sslstrip. And, I hope the communication with the external system do not involve any sensitive/personal data.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the retuen 301 inside a location "/" block it should work:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.org;

    location /non_https {
        proxy_pass http://example;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```